# Testing with Manual Dependency Injection according to Google

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, dependency-injection, architecture

There is an article from Google about [Manual Dependency Injection](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/manual). In it, they use an `Application` class that holds an `AppContainer`, which itself holds dependencies that other classes might need:

```
class AppContainer {
    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()...
    val userRepository = UserRepository(localDataSource, remoteDataSource)
}
```

An `Activity` might then do the following to get a dependency, eg. a repository:

```
val appContainer = (application as MyApplication).appContainer
val loginViewModel = LoginViewModel(appContainer.userRepository)
```

They state the following:

> Dependency injection ... enables you to swap out implementations for testing.

Can this be done with that approach (or any of the others presented on the page mentioned above)?

I tried to come up with a canonical  way and didn't find one that wouldn't involve reflection or mocking or anything of the sorts.

Comment: What is your issue with mocking?

Comment: I have used mocking to test a class that didn't use dependency injection. This was done by intercepting the call to a certain function and returning the test data. I disliked that approach, as it's very reliant on a certain implementation.

In my mind, dependency injection is used to not have to use mocking, but instead be able to pass a fake object that can be used instead of the actual one.

Comment: In my circles, we refer to that fake object as the mock object. It's usually either a Pojo which should be easy to create from a constructor or builder or it's another class that has the constructer set up with parameters that are all interfaces so mock objects can be passed in. Personally I'm not a fan of the frameworks the intercept calls either, I think they should be used a a last resort on third party classes that cannot be extended and don't have an interface. This is coming from the Java perspective.